# Difference in database size between SharePoint 2007 and 2013

Tags: database

We're migrating a system that includes a reasonable chunk of docs in SharePoint 2007. The docs have been migrated into SharePoint 2013 and now the migration has completed, it appears that the WSS_Content database in 2013 is larger than the one in 2007 (~200GB compared to ~125GB) yet it contains the same docs (the 2013 database was basically empty before the migration was done).

Are there any differences in the way 2013 works compared to 2007 that would result in a larger database for the same files? (If anything, I'd have expected the 2013 database to be smaller). Anything else that might explain the difference?

Thanks...

Comment: How did you perform migration? Database attach from 2007 to 2010 to 2013? Or with a 3rd party tool? My answer below to the log is still valid, but my statement to Shredded Storage is only correct with "Database attach" method.

Answer (score 0):

The database should be around the same size as before. Do not expect it to get smaller, as [Shredded Storage](https://www.metalogix.com/blog/dispelling-myths-shredded-storage-sharepoint-2013) only works for new documents.

I think the bigger database size is caused by a big database logfile. During migration, huge changes in the database scheme are performed. All those changes have to be written to the logfile (.ldf) before they get transferred to the datafile (.mdf). Try to [find out the size of your log](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1225/how-to-determine-sql-server-database-transaction-log-usage/) and [shrink it once](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/) if nessecary.